# The usage of word that can be both plural and singular

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Words such as [Infantry](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/infantry) and [Cavalry](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cavalry?q=cavalry) according to Oxford Learner's Dictionary can be both singular and plural.

Here is a specific example from their site.

> The infantry **was/were** guarding the bridge.

So I can choose either was or were. My question is whether the meaning is exactly the same. If there is a slight difference in meaning or nuance could you please explain what it is?

---

Another example:

> Five hundred **infantry was** marching to the north.
>
> Five hundred **infantry were** marching to the north.
>
> Five hundred **infantries were** marching to the north.

Are they have the same meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This answer describes British usage: American usage may be different).

For collectives generally, if what you are saying is true of the collective as a whole, then use the singular: *The infantry is made up of many separate units.*

If what you are saying is true of the individuals in the collective, then British usage prefers a plural: *The infantry are advancing.*

Sometimes what you are saying will be true of both the whole and the individuals; then British usage again prefers a plural: *The infantry are a proud and ancient part of the army.*

If you use an explicit number (greater than 1, of course, but I can't image "one infantry" being used), then it's plural *500 infantry are advancing.*

Comment: Generally speaking in terms of US usage (there are exceptions—like with sports teams) , the plural is used (although not always) only if individuals in the collective are doing *different* things. If they are doing the same thing, then it's normally the singular that's used. But more often, if a plural is used, a qualifying terms is used (*the group* ***is*** but *the group* ***members are***.) As for the number, if there are actually 500 different infantry units—a number I find almost impossible in practical terms, it would be *500* ***infantries*** (or *infantry* ***units***, of course.)